# On Ajax success, modal will only fire on second form submission

Tags: ajax

I have a simple form that shows a modal popup upon ajax success.  It works great the 2nd time its used in same session.  The modal will never show on the first form submission.  What could be causing the modal not to fire the first time around?  Maybe the page refresh or form reset?

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
$('#loading-indicator').show();
$("#submitbtn").prop('disabled', true);
  });

 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
   $('#loading-indicator').hide();
   $("#output").fadeTo(4000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
   $("#output").slideUp(500);
 });

$("#myform")[0].reset();
 $("#submitbtn").prop('disabled', false);
       setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
       location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
  }, 5000)
});

    
$(function () {

// init the validator
// validator files are included in the download package
// otherwise download from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

$('#myform').validator();


// when the form is submitted
$('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {

    // if the validator does not prevent form submit
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "add_report.php";

     var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);    
       $.ajax({
           url: 'add_report_do.php',
           enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
           type: 'POST',
           data: formData,
           success: function(response) {$("#successModal").modal("show");},
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           cache: false
          });
  
        return false;
    }
  })
});
<div id="successModal" class="modal modal-blur fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Fishing report successfully added.<br /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn- btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: When you use your browser's debugging tools, is the `success` callback function invoked at all on the first attempt?  And what is the purpose of the explicit page reload after 5 seconds?  Are you sure you're not just re-loading the page before the modal is displayed?  Could you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem so we can observe it?

Comment: The page does exactly as it's supposed to do no matter if the modal fires or not. I have commented out all page refresh and form reloads lines to test without success. I reloaded the page so the user could submit again without them having to refresh the page themselves.

Comment: The code above is about as minimal as I can get I believe to show you what I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out.  require.js and jquery were stepping on each other.  Added a line to require.config to isolate jquery.  Works fine now

```
define('jquery', function () { return jQuery; });
```